# How to convert string containing AM/PM to datetime in python using %p

Tags: python, datetime, strptime, strftime

I need to convert a string formatted as `'2000-01-01 12:00:00 AM'` but it doesn't matter if it is AM or PM the result is the same (see example below).

```
from datetime import datetime
frmt = '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S %p'
datetime.strptime('2000-01-01 12:00:00 AM', frmt).isoformat()
datetime.strptime('2000-01-01 12:00:00 PM', frmt).isoformat()
```

Output is:

```
'2000-01-01T12:00:00'
'2000-01-01T12:00:00'
```

I thought it could be a problem related to no definition if 12AM is midnight or noon but even when executing the same code for other different hours the result is still the same:

```
datetime.strptime('2000-01-01 06:00:00 AM', frmt).isoformat()
datetime.strptime('2000-01-01 06:00:00 PM', frmt).isoformat()
```

Output is:

```
'2000-01-01T06:00:00'
'2000-01-01T06:00:00'
```

The [strftime.org](http://strftime.org/) website says the format I am using should work, but it is not. What should I do?

Comment: You can use the dateutil module for this, check my answer below @GustavoMaia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why I use arrow.  Just makes all of this easier.

```
import arrow
frmt = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss A'
print(arrow.get('2000-01-01 12:00:00 AM', frmt))
print(arrow.get('2000-01-01 12:00:00 PM', frmt))
#datetime
print(arrow.get('2000-01-01 12:00:00 AM', frmt).datetime)
print(arrow.get('2000-01-01 12:00:00 PM', frmt).datetime)
#isoformat
print(arrow.get('2000-01-01 12:00:00 AM', frmt).isoformat())
print(arrow.get('2000-01-01 12:00:00 PM', frmt).isoformat())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dateutil.parser.parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#module-dateutil.parser) to parse any datetime string without providing a format string, this is available in the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) module

```
In [22]: from dateutil import parser                                                                                                                                                   

In [25]: parser.parse('2000-01-01 12:00:00 PM').isoformat()                                                                                                                            
Out[25]: '2000-01-01T12:00:00'

In [26]: parser.parse('2000-01-01 12:00:00 AM').isoformat()                                                                                                                            
Out[26]: '2000-01-01T00:00:00'
```